# How can I manage multiple configurations of a single Haskell program?

Tags: configuration, haskell, build-automation, conditional-compilation

What is an alternative to autotools in Haskell world? I want to be able to choose between different configurations of the same source code.

For example, there are at least two implementations of MD5 in Haskell: `Data.Digest.OpenSSL.MD5` and `Data.Digest.Pure.MD5`. I'd like to write code in such a way that it can figure out which library is already installed, and didn't require to install the other.

In C I can use Autotools/Scons/CMake + `cpp`. In Python I can catch `ImportError`. Which tools should I use in Haskell?

Comment: Thanks, Norman, this is the better title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Haskell you use Cabal configurations.  At your project top-level directory, you put a file with the extension `.cabal`, e.g., `<yourprojectname>.cabal`.  The contents are roughly:

```
Name:                myfancypackage
Version:             0.0
Description:         myfancypackage
License:             BSD3
License-file:        LICENSE
Author:              John Doe
Maintainer:          john@example.com
Build-Type:          Simple
Cabal-Version:       >=1.4

Flag pure-haskell-md5
  Description: Choose the purely Haskell MD5 implementation
  Default: False

Executable haq
  Main-is:           Haq.hs
  Build-Depends:     base-4.*
  if flag(pure-haskell-md5)
    Build-Depends:   pureMD5-0.2.*
  else
    Build-Depends:   hopenssl-1.1.*
```

The [Cabal documentation](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/authors.html) has more details, in particular the section on [Configurations](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/authors.html#configurations).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. As well as I understand, I have to use CC-Options and cpp. Right?

Comment: Right, it's called `CPP-options`, `CC` is the C compiler.  You also have to go build your project using cabal.  Take a look at the Makefile and .cabal file from one of my projects: [Scion](http://github.com/nominolo/scion/tree/master).  Also, you need to add {-# LANGUAGE CPP #-} to relevant files.

Answer (score 2):

As nominolo says, Cabal is the tool to use. In particular, the 'configurations" syntax.